# Building MobileFirst Android app without ADT (using Android Studio instead)

Tags: android, android-studio, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

As specified [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/devenv/t_installing_tools_for_android.html), I should not need to install ADT if I have Android Studio and SDK installed.

I'm trying to test this in response to a customer's question on whether or not you can use Android Studio instead of ADT. Because ADT is no longer supported as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html).

Here's my steps:

- install eclipse.
- Install MobileFirst Studio v6.3 from eclipse marketplace.
- Install Android Studio (which also installed Android SDK), able to launch Android Studio and run an empty app.
- Specify the location of Android Studio in Window > Preferences > MobileFirst.
- Create MFP project, add Android environment.
- From menus select Run As > Build All Environments.

At this point the build failed. Do I still have to install ADT in order to be able to build?

**UPDATE:**

Error Log

```
[2015-01-30 12:50:22] Starting build process: application 'demo', all environments  
[2015-01-30 12:50:29] FWLST1125W: Android build will fail because an Android SDK was not installed. Use the Android SDK Manager to install API level 19, configure your project to build with API level 19 by updating the Project Build Target in Project / Properties / Android dialog.
[2015-01-30 12:50:30] Application 'demo' with all environments build finished.
```

Comment: "the build failed" - that does not help us. How did it fail? what error did you get?

Comment: Here's the error even though I had API 19 and the latest installed: [2015-01-30 12:50:22]             Starting build process: application 'demo', all environments 
[2015-01-30 12:50:29] FWLST1125W: Android build will fail because an Android SDK was not installed. Use the Android SDK Manager to install API level 19, configure 
your project to build with API level 19 by updating the Project Build Target in Project / Properties / Android dialog. 
[2015-01-30 12:50:30]             Application 'demo' with all environments build finished.

Answer (score 0):

Because you selected the Run As > Build all, this *will* indeed give you the Warning you have mentioned since you do not have ADT installed. Because you do not have ADT installed, the usual generated Android project that Worklight/MFP generates for you will fail to generate.

If you want to open your project in Android Studio, you should right-click the Android environment and select Run As > Android Studio Project.

The project should then correctly open in Android Studio.

Comment: Thank you, Idan for the clarification. This is another problem that I have. If I select Run As > Android Studio Project, I got the following error on if I run on Windows even though I already set the path where Android Studio is installed. But it works OK in my Mac. Error message: Failed Running Android Studio: Specify location of Android Studio in Window->Preferences->MobileFirst

Comment: Make sure you point to the folder the exe is located and not to the exe itself.

Comment: I tried that, the **studio64.exe** is located at **C:\IBM\Android Studio\bin** and that's what I put there and still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the beta version (MFPF 6.3) for Windows. The solution was to install the Fix Pack `6.3.0.0-MFPF-StudioP2-IF201502141702.zip` found [here](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/quickorder?parent=ibm%7EOther%2Bsoftware&product=ibm/Other%20software/IBM%20MobileFirst%20Platform%20Foundation&release=6.3.0.0&platform=Windows&function=fixId&fixids=6.3.0.0-MFPF-IF201502141702&includeRequisites=1&includeSupersedes=0&downloadMethod=http&source=fc). After installation you must reconfigure the path of Android Studio (Windows > Preferences > MobileFirst)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will be of help, as this is a very old post. Try pointing to android studio home and not to bin folder. Some thing like **C:\IBM\Android Studio**.
I have also faced the same issue and solved it by pointing to android studio home folder.